# Code always writes filename in the output

Tags: python

I am trying to find which files have not had a relevant file with a similar filename (almost) so that I can generate them. But this code writes all file names basically whereas I want it to go through the first directory, go through the files and check if they have their equivilent `_details.txt` in the other folder, if not write the name.

I have in folder 1 those two 11.avi and 22.avi and in folder two only 11_details.txt , so am sure i should get one filename as a result

```
    import os,fnmatch
    a = open("missing_detailss5.txt", "w")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("1/"):
        for file1 in files:
            if file1.endswith(".dat"):
                    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("2/"):
                        print(str(os.path.splitext(file1)[0]) + "_details.txt")
                        print(files)
                        if not (os.path.splitext(file1)[0] + "_details.txt") in files:
                              print(str(os.path.splitext(file1)[0]) + "_details.txt is missing")
                              a.write(str(os.path.splitext(file1)[0]) + "_details.txt" + os.linesep)
    a.close()

    here is my debug >>> 
    11_details.txt
    ['22_details.txt']
    11_details.txt is missing
    22_details.txt
    ['22_details.txt']
    22_details.txt is missing
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: it basically writes all the file names

Comment: i have made a simple test with 2 files i made, it should return 1 which has a missing details relevant but it returns both

Comment: Just describe what you want your program to do, please.

Comment: i want it to go through the first directory go through the files and check if they have their equivilant _details.txt in the other folder, if not write the name

Comment: which means none have their equivilant _details.txt in the other folder.

Comment: I have in folder 1 those two New Text Document - Copy.avi and New Text Document.avi and in folder two only New Text Document_details.txt , so am sure i should get one filename as a result

Comment: I did try to use the .txt and exclude it in the if not statement and still didnt help

Comment: Are you sure your program is looking for the correct file name? Use a Python debugger to find out what filename it is actually looking for.

Comment: yes it does look exactly the same, yet it goes inside the if :(

Comment: i mean i could also see the name in the output

Comment: could re edit the post to give us examples of  a sample input and a sample output.

Comment: i did add the sample,

Comment: sorry, for a moment i put the wrong filename, coz i have multiple samples am testing with

Comment: ah I understand! here is a quick easy way, I will write the code for it when I reach home if you can't figure out. just make 2 lists of the files, remove the extension, and the substract the two. the remainder are the missing files. and yes you can subtract 2 lists in python.

Comment: whats the problem :) its after 12  here i need to run this over a large database :P any quick tip ?

Answer (score 0):

I just corrected your code directly without writing new code, you just missed a txt extension on the comparaison if.

```
import os
a = open("missing_detailss4.txt", "w")
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk("1/"):
    for file in files:
      if file.endswith(".avi"):
             for root, dirs, files in os.walk("2/"):
                  if not (str(os.path.splitext(file)[0]) + "_details.txt") in files:
                       a.write(str(os.path.splitext(file)[0]) + "_details.txt" + os.linesep)
 a.close()
```

Comment: but that was just for testing, i did try both with .txt and without :P

Comment: even with this shit its not working                     if not fnmatch.fnmatch(os.path.splitext(file)[0]  + "_details", '*.txt'):

Comment: I mean i can see the filename existing in the debug mode when i look at the files list ! with the exact name and extension

Comment: you are comparing samplefile_details with samplefile_details.txt in your version so you will always get false and you will get all files.

Comment: thats the debug output >>> 
11_details.txt
['22_details.txt']
22_details.txt
['22_details.txt']
>>>

Comment: but no, its actually right, you can see the debug, one of the only should be returned !

Comment: It's working for me after the little fix.  dir 1/ has 1.avi 2.avi , 3.avi, 4.avi      dir 2/ has 1_details.txt when I run the script missing_details4.txt contains: 4_details.txt
2_details.txt
3_details.txt

Comment: I get the exact thing, you can see in the above debug log, they should not be both written

Comment: here is my debug >>> 
11_details.txt
['22_details.txt']
11_details.txt is missing
22_details.txt
['22_details.txt']
22_details.txt is missing

Comment: okay could edit your original post, please put the content of your first dir, the content of your 2nd dir, and the content of the missing_details4.txt after running. I want to see if we are missing something.

Comment: I printed it all in the debug above in the question

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, the files ending in "_details.txt" are supposed to be in the same (relative) directory. That is, "1/some/path/file.avi" should have a corresponding file "2/some/path/file_details.txt".  If that's the case, you need not iterate twice:

```
import os
with open("missing_detailss5.txt", "w") as outfile:
    path1 = '1/'
    path2 = '2/'
    allowed_extensions = ['.dat', '.avi']
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path1):
        for file1 in files:
            file1, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            if ext not in allowed_extensions: continue
            path2 = os.path.join(path2, os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file1 + '_details.txt'), path1))
            if not os.path.exists(path2):
                print(os.path.basename(path2) + ' is missing.')
                outfile.write(os.path.basename(path2) + os.linesep)
```

If you don't care about which extensions to check for in the first folder, then delete `allowed_extensions = ['.dat', '.avi']` and `if ext not in allowed_extensions: continue` lines, and change `file1, ext = os.path.splitext(file)` to `file1 = os.path.splitext(file)[0]`.